# Square root property of congruences

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I'm trying to understand something written in my textbook. Suppose $n=pq$ is the product of two primes and we know the four solutions $x \equiv \pm a, \pm b$ of $x^2 \equiv y \ $(mod $\ n)$. Then $a \equiv b \ $ (mod $p$) and $a \equiv -b  \ $(mod $q$), or $a \equiv b \ $(mod $q$) and $a \equiv -b  \ $(mod $p$).

Can someone explain why this is true?

Comment: The linked dupes show in detail how the roots combine via CRT. By there the roots of $\,x^2\equiv a^2\pmod{\!pq}$ are $\,x\equiv \pm(a,a),\,\pm(a,-a)\pmod{\!p,q}.\,$  The first case is $\,x\equiv \pm a\pmod{\!pq},\,$ and the 2nd (your $b)$ is the mixed sign case: the  solution of $\,x\equiv a\pmod{\!p},\,x\equiv -a\pmod{\!q}$ (your $\,b),\,$ and its negative, exactly as you claim.

Answer (score 0):

$a^2\equiv b^2\pmod n\iff n|a^2-b^2=(a+b)(a-b)\implies p,q|(a+b)(a-b)$

$\implies p|a+b$ or $a-b$ and $q|a+b$ or $a-b$

$\implies a\equiv -b\pmod p$ or $a\equiv b\pmod p$ and $a\equiv-b\pmod q$ or $a\equiv b\pmod q$.

But if $a\equiv b\pmod p$ and $a\equiv b\pmod q$ then $a\equiv b\mod n$, so $a$ and $b$ are not distinct.

Likewise if $a\equiv -b\pmod p $ and $a\equiv -b\pmod q$ then $a\equiv-b\pmod n$,

so again $\pm a$ and $\pm b$ are not distinct.

Therefore, the possibilities are $a\equiv b\pmod p$ and $a\equiv -b\pmod q$

or $a\equiv -b\pmod p$ and $a\equiv b\pmod q$.

Answer (score 0):

Just an example.

The square roots of $-3 \equiv 4 \pmod 7$ are $\pm 2 \pmod 7.$

The square roots of $-3 \equiv 36 \pmod{13}$ are $\pm 6 \pmod{13}$

By the Chinese Remainder Theorem, one of the pairs comes from $19,$ because  $$ 19 = 3 \cdot 7 - 2 = 13 + 6.$$ That pair, $\pm 19 \pmod {91}$ are
$$  19, 72 \pmod{91} $$ So we are naming $a = 19.$

The other pair comes from $33,$ because  $$ 33 = 5 \cdot 7 - 2 = 3 \cdot 13 - 6.$$ That pair, $\pm 33 \pmod {91}$ are
$$  33, 58 \pmod{91} $$ So we are naming $b = 33.$

Then $p=7, \; \; $  $q = 13.$

Let's see, $33-19 = 14$ is a multiple of $7,$ so $a \equiv b \pmod 7.$

Finally, $33+19 = 52$ is a multiple of $13$ so $a+b \equiv 0 \pmod {13} \; , \; \; $ also written $a \equiv -b \pmod {13}.$